# De Re, Counterfactuals, and rigidity

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, modal-logic, kripke

This is going to come off as vague or obscure; but, I hope the idea is performatively expressed:

Two questions:

Do you think that Kripke would argue that the impossibility of *de re* counterfactuals only obtains for rigid designators?

And the following question as to one might reasonably speculate that *de re* statements are *a fortiori* rigid?

Comment: The first question might come off as opinion-based, but the answers to it will surely be interesting. I hope you get some answers because the questions are quite interesting. In fact, both answers are escaping me at the moment.

Comment: You mean if a=b implies □(a=b) then a and b designate rigidly? I don't think so. If a=b is analytic then □(a=b) even if a and b designate non-rigidly. Trivially, take a the last king of France, and b the same as a.

Comment: Let me provide an example @Conifold: 

De re (rigid counterfactual): Ralph believes someone is a spy. (True in possible worlds where Ralph is not treating his paranoid schizophrenia.)

De dicto (non-rigid counterfactual): Nobody is out to get Ralph because of XYZ.